# help needed with adding picture from url!

Tags: iphone, image, twitter, mgtwitterengine

i've managed to incorporate the twitter api into my app and i can call all the data and put it into my app, except for the image.

i've managed to find tuts on how to get the picture if you provide the url, but i want to get the addy from my dictionary to then be put into my uiimageview.

Any help would be appreciated, here is what i have sourced

`NSData *imageData = 
   [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfUrl:
       [NSString 
           stringWithContentsOfUrl: 
             [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com"]
           encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
           error: nil
       ]
   ];`

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

[marcaBackground setImage:image];
[imageData release];
[image release];

this is what i have already set up`-(NSString*)author {

```
return [[contents objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
```

`

```
NSString *author=[(Tweet*)[auth objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] author];
```

could someone please advise me on what needs changing for it to work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfUrl: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]];
```

The rest is correct.

Comment: Nice one dude, I'll give that a go tomorrow and let ya know

Comment: unfortunately i can't get this to work, my noob-ness exceeds me. unless i can find a clear tut i think i'll have to implement the picture at a later date.                 thanks for your help